# webpack html-loaders lowercase angular 2 built-in directives

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-file-loader, webpack-html-loader

I am using html-loader to load my html template and file-loader to load my images that are in the template.  This run just fine in dev but when I run build:prod and run the output, I get a template parse error.

It appears that all angular2 built-in directives (e.g., *ngFor, *ngIf) are all converted to all lowercase (e.g., *ngfor, *ngif) which cases the error.

I tried create a separate project and this time, not using any built-in directives from angular 2, everything works fine.

Is there another loader I can use?  How do i correctly load these templates along with the images used by these templates?

here is my webpack.config

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry:'./src/main.ts',

    output:{
        path:'./dist',
        filename:'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module:{
        loaders:[{test:/\.ts$/, loader:'ts-loader'},
        { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'] },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader' },
      {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: "file-loader"},
      //{ test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
      //{ test: require.resolve('jquery'), loader: 'expose?jQuery!expose?$' }
      ]

    /*   loaders: [
      // .ts files for TypeScript
      { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'] },
      { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'] },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' }
    ]*/
    },
    resolve:{
        root: [ path.join(__dirname, 'src') ], //add this for dev server
        extensions:['','.js','.ts']
    },
    plugins:[

        //inject all the files above into this file
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
                $: 'jquery',
                jquery: 'jquery'
        })

    ]


}
```

And below is the parse error that I get.

> Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'routerlink' since it
>   isn't a known property of 'a'. ("r> Menu   ][routerlink]=r.routerLink
>   [routerlinkactive]="['active']">{{r.text}}   
>    "): t@0:359 Can't bind to 'routerlinkactive' since it isn't a
>   known property of 'a'. (""item ui red" *ngfor="let r of routes"> ][routerlinkactive]="['active']">{{r.text}}     Home
>     Menu  ]*ngfor="let r of routes">  Home   Menu  [ERROR ->]  ]*ngif=bolWidthLess1000>
>
> [ERROR ->] 
>   ][routerlink]=r.routerLink>  ][routerlink]=r.routerLink
>   [routerlinkactive]="['active']">{{r.text}}  
>    ][routerlinkactive]="['active']">{{r.text}}     "): t@0:674 Can't bind to
>   'ngforOf' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("/div>
>
> ]*ngfor="let r of routes" class="item mainmenu" [routerlink]=r.routerLink> "): t@0:540 Property binding ngforOf not used by any directive
>   on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled
>   correctly and all directives are listed in the "directives" section.
>   (">     [ERROR ->] {{r.text}}   
>    ]*ngif=!bolWidthLess1000> "): t@0:512 Property binding ngif
>   not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the
>   property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in
>   the "directives" section. ("routerlink]=r.routerLink
>   [routerlinkactive]="['active']">{{r.text}}   
>    [ERROR ->]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the minimize param to false in the loader query as shown below.

`{ test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html?minimize=false' }`

**Or**

You can upgrade the `html-loader` to `0.4.3` and use the following configuration.

`{ test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html?minimize=true&caseSensitive: true}`

Comment: only 4.3 has the caseSensitive option?  I am using 4.4 and it doesn't seem to work so just did minimize=false.

Comment: I have spent best part of the day tracking this down, so thank you both for posting!

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47615772/9268047, it worked for me