# Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'select'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm attempting to create a very simple select with values from an `enum`.  This is the [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s3t1f7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

I've taken the code directly from another [working stackblitz implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/akita-todos-app?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftodos%2Ffilter%2Ffilters.component.ts) so I'm not sure why the error:

> Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'select'. ("][formControl]="control">
>   {{filter}"):

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'input' - angular2 material Autocomplete issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220348/cant-bind-to-formcontrol-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input-angular)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to import `ReactiveFormsModule` to your `imports`. Your `app.module.ts` doesn't contain all the correct imports: `imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ]`

Answer (score 0):

you may use formControlName="control"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31399437)