# Angular error message: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: angular, typescript

My code environment is Angular 9, and when I set up and example with Material, I met this error:

error NG8002: Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

I have already added the corresponding imports in all the corresponding modules in my application but still the error keeps appearing.

**This is my code**

My app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthenticationModule } from './modules/authentication/authentication.module';
import { SharedModule } from './modules/shared/shared/shared.module'
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LandingModule } from './modules/landing/landing.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AuthenticationModule,
    SharedModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      extend: true,
      isolate: false
    }),
    LandingModule
  ],
  providers: [HttpClientModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

My shared.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot(),
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    FormsModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule
  ]
})

export class SharedModule { }
```

forgot.password.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'segura-forgot-password',
  templateUrl: './forgot-password.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forgot-password.component.scss']
})
export class ForgotPasswordComponent implements OnInit {

  email = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]);

  getErrorMessage() {
    if (this.email.hasError('required')) {
      return 'You must enter a value';
    }

    return this.email.hasError('email') ? 'Not a valid email' : '';
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

and my forgot.password.html

```
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Enter your email</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="pat@example.com" [FormControl]="email" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Authentication module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AuthenticationRoutingModule } from './authentication-routing.module';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './components/forgot-password/forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared/shared.module';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register/register.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login/login.component';
import { LegalTermsComponent } from './components/legal-terms/legal-terms/legal-terms.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent, ForgotPasswordComponent, RegisterComponent, LegalTermsComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AuthenticationRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ]
})
export class AuthenticationModule { }
```

Comment: I think You need to import the formsModule

Comment: Where is `[formGroup]` in your code? and can you also share forgot password module code too

Comment: @AlokTakshak Yes, it is importing from the share.module.ts

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti Typing error is FormControl that generates me the error 8002.

Comment: Are you importing sharedmodule into the forgot password module?

Comment: hope this will resolve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220348/cant-bind-to-formcontrol-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input-angular

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti Yes, I have another module called authentication that imports both the sharing module and the forgot password module, I already edited the code

Comment: @deepak Yes, I followed the steps of the shared post, but it did not generate the expected solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **shared.module.ts**, you are just importing `ReactiveFormsModule`. You also need to export it to use in other modules

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    ...
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ...
  ]
})
```

And in the **forgot.password.html** the syntax is

```
<input matInput placeholder="pat@example.com" [formControl]="email" required>
```

Not `[FormControl]="email"`

Comment: You were right, it was called the input with the FormControl and it must be formControl and I was forgetting about the exports. Thank you very much!